# Disabling accelerator keys on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Apologies if this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer to it on this site.

I am wondering if there is a way to disable accelerator keyboard shortcuts on Windows 7. By  accelerator shortcuts I am referring to the keyboard shortcuts that allow me to access a drop menu on Windows applications by pressing: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + first letter of the drop menu.

For example, say I have the following list of menus:

[image]

On Windows I can often press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the File menu, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open the Edit menu.

Is there a way to disable them?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use an [Auto](http://www.autohotkey.com/)Hotkey script to prevent the application from receiving the shortcuts one by one:

```
!F::
!E::
{
  ;do nothing
}
```